# I can't filter elements in a collection with Enumerable.Where()

Tags: c#, linq

I found a strange behavior when I was using Linq.

The situation is that I want to make a collection which contains integers like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], and I will remove the first element in the collection in each iteration of a for-loop.

But when I executed my code, I found that the count of elements in the collection didn't really reduce as what I expected. Instead, it kept remaining 4 elements after the first iteration.

Here is my source code:

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
int currentNumber;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    currentNumber = collection.FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(currentNumber); //It prints endless 1 2 1 2 1 2...
    collection = collection.Where(number => currentNumber != number);
}
```

I inspected the process with debugger and found the elements after executing `collection.Where()` were like:

```
Iteration 1: [2, 3, 4, 5]
Iteration 2: [1, 3, 4, 5]
Iteration 3: [2, 3, 4, 5]
Iteration 4: [1, 3, 4, 5]
...
```

This confused me because it seemed to always take [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as the source to execute `Where()` in each iteration.

But when I moved the declaration of `currentNumber` into the for-loop, everything worked as what I expected.

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int currentNumber; //Move the declaration to this line
    currentNumber = collection.FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(currentNumber); //It correctly prints 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0
    collection = collection.Where(number => currentNumber != number);
}
```

Please tell me why it worked correctly after I moved the declaration into the for-loop.

Comment: Capture issue. You should create a copy of `currentNumber` inside the loop. Or just declare it inside the loop.

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AccessToModifiedClosure.html

Comment: Note that you seem to have a misunderstanding of what `Where` does / what you are doing. Each call of `Where` creates a new iterator that runs the test every time the collection is enumerated. This happens when `FirstOrDefault` is called. So you are piling up a collection of tests against the value of `currentNumber` which changes through the loop, which means you are just uselessly testing the same thing over and over again. What you are doing is very bad practice.